# How to set Hana output parameter in c#

Tags: c#, .net, hana

Is there any way to set output parameter in hana sp in c#. For explanation see the below code

```
HanaParameter param21 = cmd.CreateParameter();
param21.HanaDbType = ?
param21.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
param21.ParameterName = "ET_CUST_RESULT";
cmd.Parameters.Add(param21);
```

as you can see what is the `HanaDbType.?;` for this parameter. If anyone have experienced this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is there not a HanaDbType enum?

Eg.

```
param21.HanaDbType = HanaDbType.AlphaNum;
```

Comment: `ET_CUST_RESULT` is something like `select * from table`. Basically it out put a table. So how can we set it